# Angular StaticInjectorError with Material Snackbar

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to add Material Snackbar to my app as a Service.

So, in my notification.service.ts, I added:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {

  snackbar_notification: Subject<string> = new Subject();
  constructor() {}
  setSnackbarNotification(message: string) {
    this.snackbar_notification.next(message);
  }
}
```

In my app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private notificationService: NotificationService,
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar
  ) {

    this.notificationService.snackbar_notification.subscribe(message => {
      this.snackBar.open(message);
    });

  }
}
```

I trigger the snackbar from a component like:

```
this.notificationService.setSnackbarNotification('this is a notification');
```

The code was working fine before I made the above changes in above 3 files.

Now, it's giving me error during execution:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(Xs)[e -> e]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[e -> e]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for e!
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Import the module:

```
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
```

And add it to your module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatSnackBarModule,
    ],
    providers: [

    ],
})
```

Make sure you are adding to the parent module of notification and component you are using in it.

Comment: Add this to which module? Notification module or app module?

Comment: @user5155835 I am not sure about the order of your modules, but try Notification Module first and then App Module.